# Prevent lnjection on large sql select statement using like and %

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-injection

I have a large sql query which I am trying to prevent injection on.
Because the query uses like and '%' on the variables I do not know how to format it and my usual method of

```
$sql = "INSERT into UsedBook ( userId, bookId, price, description ) VALUES 
(?,?,?,?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiis", $userId, $bookId, $price, 
$description);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Doesn't fit the format.

Here is my large query. Look near the bottom for the like statements with the variables.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Offering.offeringId, UsedBook.saleId, 
UsedBook.bookId, UsedBook.price,
UsedBook.timeStamp, Book.bookName, Classes.classNumber, Instructor.name,
Classes.departmentName, Offering.section, Users.email, UsedBook.description
FROM UsedBook, Book, Classes, Offering, Instructor, RequiredBook, Users
WHERE UsedBook.bookId = Book.bookId
and Classes.classId = RequiredBook.classId and Book.bookId = 
RequiredBook.bookId
and Classes.classId = Offering.classId and Offering.instructorId = 
Instructor.instructorId
and Offering.semesterId = $semester and UsedBook.userId = Users.userId and 
UsedBook.userId != $userId
and Classes.departmentName like '$departmentName%' and Classes.classNumber 
like '$classNumber%'
and Book.bookName like '$bookName%' and Offering.section like '$section%'";
```

Comment: what errors did you get when using `mysqli_error($conn)` if it failed and in a conditional statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can still use a prepared statement, you just need to incorporate the `%` into the bound parameter e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM UsedBook WHERE bookName LIKE ?";
$param = "$bookName%";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Awesome I was able to figure out what to write from that. Thanks!